# Plotting elliptical paraboloid in matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I plot an elliptical paraboloid in MATLAB with `surf()` function, using parametric equations with 2 variables **u** and **v**? The equation looks like

```
r = {ucos{v}, u^2,5usin{v}}
```

I understand that I need to make a meshgrid from **u** and **v**, but what to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it the following way:

```
%// Create three function handles with the components of you function
fx = @(u,v) u.* cos(v);  %// Notice that we use .*
fy = @(u,v) u.^2;        %// and .^ because we want to apply
fz = @(u,v) 5.*u.*sin(v);%// multiplication and power component-wise.

%// Create vectors u and v within some range with 100 points each
u = linspace(-10,10, 100);
v = linspace(-pi,pi, 100);

%// Create a meshgrid from these ranges
[uu,vv] = meshgrid(u, v);

%// Create the surface plot using surf
surf(fx(uu,vv),  fy(uu,vv),  fz(uu,vv));

%// Optional: Interpolate the color and do not show the grid lines
shading interp;

%// Optional: Set the aspect ratio of the axes to 1:1:1 so proportions
%//           are displayed correctly.
axis equal;
```

I added some annotation, because you seem to be new to Matlab.